# How can I store an array slot to use between functions?

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to make a tic tac toe game that allows you to play against a human enemy or the computer. I'm trying to code some basic AI that will prevent you from winning by scanning the board to see if you have 2 X's or O's next to each other or in opposite corners in a column/row/diagonal and I need a way to tell the computer if and which tile it needs to print on to prevent you from winning. My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

void initializeBoard(); //initialize the board //
void drawBoard(); //draw it on the window //
void player_1_move(); //check if player 1 made a valid move and update the board
void player_2_move(); //check if player 2 made a valid move and update the board

//AI functions
void pickTile(); //picks a tile based on available information
void computerTurn(); //checks if the computer is going first or second

char* isThereaWinningMove(); //checks if the user is abou to win
char tempcT;

int checkWin(); //checks if either player has won at the end of every turn and if so ends the game and declares a winner //

char board[3][3]; //3x3 tic tac toe board

int main(){
    
    int win = 0;
    
    printf("==============");
    printf("\n TIC TAC TOE \n");
    printf("==============\n");
    printf("The World's Number 1 Multiplayer Game! \n\n");
    
    initializeBoard();
    
    //let's the user pick the gamemode
    int x;
    
    printf("Press 1 to PLAY AGAINST A HUMAN or 0 to PLAY AGAINST AI: \n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    
    while(x!=0 && x!=1){
        printf("Invalid input. Press 1 to PLAY AGAINST A HUMAN or 0 to PLAY AGAINST AI: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
    }
    if(x==1){ //pvp
        do{
            drawBoard();
            printf("\n\n");
        
            player_1_move(); //player 1 (X) moves
            drawBoard(); //update the board with each move
            win=checkWin(); //did player 1 win?
            if(win==1){
                printf("\nPlayer 1 has won!");
                break;
            }
            
            printf("\n\n");
            player_2_move(); //player 2 (O) moves
            drawBoard(); //update the board with each move
            win=checkWin(); //did player 2 win?
            if(win==1){
                printf("\nPlayer 2 has won!");
                break;
            }
        }while(1);
    }
    else{ //pvc
        computerTurn();
        if(tempcT == 'O'){ //if the player is going first
            do{
                srand( (unsigned int) time(NULL) ); //initialize random seed
                drawBoard();
                printf("\n\n");
            
                player_1_move(); //user (X) moves first
                drawBoard(); //update the board with each move
                win=checkWin(); //did player 1 win?
                if(win==1){
                    printf("\nPlayer has won!");
                    break;
                }
                //computer turn
                printf("\n\n");
                pickTile(); //picks available tile
                win=checkWin();
                if(win == 1){
                    printf("\nI win!");
                    break;
                }
            }while(1);
        }
        else{ //if the computer goes first
            do{
                
                //computer turn
                srand( (unsigned int) time(NULL) ); //initialize random seed
                printf("\n\n");
                pickTile(); //picks available tile
                win=checkWin();
                if(win == 1){
                    printf("\nI win!");
                    break;
                }
                
                //player turn
                drawBoard();
                printf("\n\n");
            
                player_1_move(); //user (X) moves first
                drawBoard(); //update the board with each move
                win=checkWin(); //did player 1 win?
                if(win==1){
                    printf("\nPlayer has won!");
                    break;
                }
            }while(1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

//initialize the board
void initializeBoard(){
    
    int i, j;
    
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        for(j=0; j<=2; j++){
            board[i][j]= ' ';
        }
    }
    
}

//draws the board on the window
void drawBoard(){
    int t;
    
    for(t=0; t<=2; t++){
        printf(" %c | %c | %c ", board[t][0], board[t][1], board[t][2]);
        if(t!=2){
            printf("\n---|---|---\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//checks if there is a winner at the end of every turn
int checkWin(){
    
    int i;
    
    //checks rows
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(board[i][0]==board[i][1] && board[i][0]==board[i][2] && board[i][0]!= ' '){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    //checks columns
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(board[0][i]==board[1][i] && board[0][i]==board[2][i] && board[0][i]!= ' '){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    //checks diagonals from top left to bottom right
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(board[0][0]==board[1][1] && board[1][1]==board[2][2] && board[0][0]!= ' '){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    //checks diagonals from bottom left to top right
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(board[2][0]==board[1][1] && board[1][1]==board[0][2] && board [2][0]!= ' '){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}

//player 1 (X) move
void player_1_move(){
    
    int x, y;
    
    //player 1 picks coordinates on the board
    printf("Player 1, please pick a row (1-3): ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Now pick a column (1-3): ");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    
    x--, y--;
    
    //check if it's a valid tile
    while(1){
        if(x<0 || x>2){
            if(y<0 || y>2){
                printf("Invalid tile, please enter a valid tile (same order as before, 1-3): ");
                scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
                x--, y--;
            }
            else{
                printf("Invalid row, please try again (1-3): ");
                scanf("%d", &x);
                x--;
            }
        }
        else if(y<0 || y>2){
            printf("Invalid column, please try again (1-3): ");
            scanf("%d", &y);
            y--;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    
    //check if the tile is free
    while(board[x][y]=='O' || board[x][y]=='X'){
        printf("Invalid move, please enter valid coordinates (same order as before, 1-3): ");
        scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
        x--, y--;
    }
    
    board[x][y]='X';
}

//player 2 (O) move
void player_2_move(){
    
    int x, y;

    //player 2 picks a tile
    printf("Player 2, please pick a row (1-3): ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Now pick a column (1-3): ");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    x--, y--; 

    //check if it's a valid tile
    while(1){
        if(x<0 || x>2){
            if(y<0 || y>2){
                printf("Invalid tile, please enter a valid tile (same order as before, 1-3): ");
                scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
                x--, y--;
            }
            else{
                printf("Invalid row, please try again (1-3): ");
                scanf("%d", &x);
                x--;
            }
        }
        else if(y<0 || y>2){
            printf("Invalid column, please try again (1-3): ");
            scanf("%d", &y);
            y--;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    
    //check if the tile is free
    while(board[x][y]=='O' || board[x][y]=='X'){
        printf("Invalid move, please enter valid coordinates (same order as before, 1-3): ");
        scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
        x--, y--;
    }
    
    board[x][y]='O';
}

//AI functions

//checks if the computer is going first or second
void computerTurn(){
    
    int x;
    
    printf("Press 1 if you'd like to GO FIRST and 0 if you'd like to GO SECOND: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    while(x!=0 && x!=1){
        printf("Invalid input. Press 1 if you'd like to GO FIRST and 0 if you'd like to GO SECOND: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
    }
    if(x==1){
        printf("OK, the player is going first.\n\n");
        tempcT = 'O';
    }
    else{
        printf("OK, I'm going first.\n\n");
        tempcT = 'X';
    }
}

//if there is a winning move available on the AI's turn
char* isThereaWinningMove(){
    int i;
    
    //checks rows
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(board[i][0]==board[i][1] && board[i][1] == ' '){
            return &board[i][2];
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(board[i][0]==board[i][2] && board[i][1] == ' '){ 
            return &board[i][1];
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(board[i][1]==board[i][2] && board[i][0] == ' '){
            return &board[i][0];
        }
    }
    
    //checks columns
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(board[0][i]==board[2][i] && board[1][i] == ' '){
            return &board[1][i];
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(board[0][i]==board[1][i] && board[2][i] == ' '){
            return &board[2][i];
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(board[1][i]==board[2][i] && board[0][i] == ' '){
            return &board[0][i];
        }
    }
    
    //checks diagonals from top left to bottom right
    if(board[1][1]==board[2][2] && board[0][0] == ' '){
        return &board[0][0];
    }
    if(board[0][0]==board[2][2] && board[1][1] == ' '){
        return &board[1][1];
    }
    if(board[0][0]==board[1][1] && board[2][2] == ' '){
        return &board[2][2];
    }
    //checks diagonals from bottom left to top right
    if(board[1][1]==board[0][2] && board [2][0] == ' '){
        return &board[2][0];
    }
    if(board[2][0]==board[1][1] && board [0][2] ==' '){
        return &board[0][2];
    }
    if(board[2][0]==board[0][2] && board [1][1] == ' '){
        return &board[1][1];
    }
    return 0;
}

//picks a tile based on available information
void pickTile(){
    int rndX, rndY;
    char *p = isThereaWinningMove();
    
    //did the computer detect a winning move?
    if(p != 0){
        *p = tempcT;
    }
    
    //if not, pick a random available tile
    else{
        while(1){
            rndX = rand()%3;
            rndY = rand()%3;
            
            if(board[rndX][rndY] == ' '){
                board[rndX][rndY] = tempcT;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Playing against a human seems to work just fine. I only have a problem with assigning tempcT's value to whatever array slot the isThereaWinningMove function will return. The code I've written now only doesn't actually run because of 2 compiler errors:

[Error] assignment of function 'char isThereaWinningMove()'
[Error] cannot convert 'int' to 'char()' in assignment

Comment: *isThereaWinningMove* is a function, doing `isThereaWinningMove = 'tempcT'`  you try to assign a function with an (invalid) char , what is your goal ?

Comment: out of that you have several calls of *isThereaWinningMove* done for nothing because you loose the result, what is the goal again ?

Comment: also `scanf("%d", x)`is invalid you wanted `scanf("%d", &x)`

Comment: you call *srand* several times with very probably the same value (program runs in the same second), so your very probably get the same value for all your *rndX* and *rndY*, do not do that, call it **one** time at the beginning of *main*

Comment: isThereaWinningMove is supposed to be called whenever the computer has its turn from within the computerTurn function and if any of the if statements are true I need to tell the computer to make a move on the corresponding tile.

Comment: for that you need to check the result of *isThereaWinningMove*, but you do not out of *pickTile* ... to try to assign your function

Comment: deleted C++ tag as your code is 'C' . It will not compile as C++ program.

Comment: also I need srand in case none of the if statements in isThereaWinningMove are true so the computer picks a random tile and checks if it's available before playing. if I call it once in main then rand() will always return the same number, no?

Comment: no, this is the reverse about *srand*, you must call it **one** time, after this is the job of *rand* to return pseudo random values, look at *srand/rand* manual

Comment: ok I fixed srand, but how would I tell the computer which tile to pick if isThereaWinningMove doesn't return 0? Would I have to just integrate it within the pickTile function?

Comment: what do you want to do ? do you want to modify the `board[i][j]` returned by *isThereaWinningMove* in case it does not return 0 ? if yes you can return the address of the element rather than its value, so `char * isThereaWinningMove(...)` and `char *  p = isThereaWinningMove(); if (p != 0) *p = tempcT;` and of course in *isThereaWinningMove* replace all `return board[i][..]` by `return &board[i][..]`

Comment: how exactly does this work? im now getting `[Error] cannot convert 'char* (*)()' to 'char*' in initialization` and I'm not very good with pointers

Comment: you very probably missed "()", look what I written. `isThereaWinningMove()`calls the function but `isThereaWinningMove`is the function

Comment: OK, this works. tyvm! I got some logic issues to iron out but it shouldn't be hard

Comment: Finally I put an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said through remarks to your question :

> [Error] assignment of function 'char isThereaWinningMove()' [Error] cannot convert 'int' to 'char()' in assignment

*isThereaWinningMove* is a function, doing `isThereaWinningMove = 'tempcT' you try to assign a function with an (invalid) char` which as no sense.

Some other remarks :

- Out of that you have several calls of *isThereaWinningMove* done for nothing because you loose the result.
- `scanf("%d", x)`is invalid you wanted `scanf("%d", &x)`
- You call *srand* several times with very probably the same value (program runs in the same second), so you very probably get the same value for all your *rndX* and *rndY*, you must call *srand* one time at the beginning of main.

In fact you want to modify the cell whose value is return by *isThereaWinningMove*, in C (and then C++) you can return the address of the cell rather than the cell value :

```
char * isThereaWinningMove(); //checks if there is a winning move available

...

char * isThereaWinningMove(){
    int i;
    
    //checks rows
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(board[i][0]==board[i][1] && board[i][0]!= ' '){
            return &board[i][2];
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(board[i][0]==board[i][2] && board[i][0]!= ' '){ 
            return &board[i][1];
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(board[i][1]==board[i][2] && board[i][0]!= ' '){
            return &board[i][0];
        }
    }
    
    //checks columns
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(board[0][i]==board[2][i] && board[0][i]!= ' '){
            return &board[1][i];
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(board[0][i]==board[1][i] && board[0][i]!= ' '){
            return &board[2][i];
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(board[1][i]==board[2][i] && board[0][i]!= ' '){
            return &board[0][i];
        }
    }
    
    //checks diagonals from top left to bottom right
    if(board[1][1]==board[2][2] && board[0][0]!= ' '){
        return &board[0][0];
    }
    if(board[0][0]==board[2][2] && board[0][0]!= ' '){
        return &board[1][1];
    }
    if(board[0][0]==board[1][1] && board[0][0]!= ' '){
        return &board[2][2];
    }
    //checks diagonals from bottom left to top right
    if(board[1][1]==board[0][2] && board [2][0]!= ' '){
        return &board[2][0];
    }
    if(board[2][0]==board[1][1] && board [2][0]!= ' '){
        return &board[0][2];
    }
    if(board[2][0]==board[0][2] && board [2][0]!= ' '){
        return &board[1][1];
    }
    return 0;
}

...

void pickTile(){
    int rndX, rndY, i;
    
    //did the computer detect a winning move?
    char * p = isThereaWinningMove();
    
    if(p != 0){
        *p = tempcT;
    }
    
    //if not, pick a random available tile
    else{
...
```

an other way is to do the assignment in *isThereaWinningMove* and return something else that 0 when you did

```
int isThereaWinningMove(); //checks if there is a winning move available

...

int isThereaWinningMove(){
    int i;
    
    //checks rows
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(board[i][0]==board[i][1] && board[i][0]!= ' '){
            board[i][2] = tempcT;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(board[i][0]==board[i][2] && board[i][0]!= ' '){ 
            board[i][1] = tempcT;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(board[i][1]==board[i][2] && board[i][0]!= ' '){
            board[i][0] = tempcT;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    //checks columns
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(board[0][i]==board[2][i] && board[0][i]!= ' '){
            board[1][i] = tempcT;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(board[0][i]==board[1][i] && board[0][i]!= ' '){
            board[2][i] = tempcT;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(board[1][i]==board[2][i] && board[0][i]!= ' '){
            board[0][i] = tempcT;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    //checks diagonals from top left to bottom right
    if(board[1][1]==board[2][2] && board[0][0]!= ' '){
        board[0][0] = tempcT;
        return 1;
    }
    if(board[0][0]==board[2][2] && board[0][0]!= ' '){
        board[1][1] = tempcT;
        return 1;
    }
    if(board[0][0]==board[1][1] && board[0][0]!= ' '){
        board[2][2] = tempcT;
        return 1;
    }
    //checks diagonals from bottom left to top right
    if(board[1][1]==board[0][2] && board [2][0]!= ' '){
        board[2][0] = tempcT;
        return 1;
    }
    if(board[2][0]==board[1][1] && board [2][0]!= ' '){
        board[0][2] = tempcT;
        return 1;
    }
    if(board[2][0]==board[0][2] && board [2][0]!= ' '){
        board[1][1] = tempcT;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

...

//picks a tile based on available information
void pickTile(){
    int rndX, rndY, i;
    
    //did the computer detect a winning move?
    if (isThereaWinningMove() == 0){
        //if not, pick a random available tile
        while(1){
...
```

Whatever the way to do, also removing the useless variable *i* in *pickTile* and removing the calls of *isThereaWinningMove* in *main* some other problems appear at the execution, for instance I can have :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall t.cpp 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out


 TIC TAC TOE 

The World's Number 1 Multiplayer Game! 

Press 1 to PLAY AGAINST A HUMAN or 0 to PLAY AGAINST AI: 0
Press 1 if you'd like to GO FIRST and 0 if you'd like to GO SECOND: 1
OK, the player is going first.   |   |   
---|---|---
   |   |   
---|---|---
   |   |   


Player 1, please pick a row (1-3): 2
Now pick a column (1-3): 2
   |   |   
---|---|---
   | X |   
---|---|---
   |   |   


   |   |   
---|---|---
   | X |   
---|---|---
 O |   |   


Player 1, please pick a row (1-3): 1
Now pick a column (1-3): 1
 X |   |   
---|---|---
   | X |   
---|---|---
 O |   |   


 O |   |   
---|---|---
   | X |   
---|---|---
 O |   |   


Player 1, please pick a row (1-3): ^C
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

As you can see the program got the cell 1-1 I got before it.

The reason is simple, *isThereaWinningMove*` can get a cell without checking it is free, so for instance

```
    if(board[i][0]==board[i][1] && board[i][0]!= ' '){
        board[i][2] = tempcT;
    return 1;
    }
```

must be

```
    if((board[i][0]==board[i][1] && board[i][0]!= ' ') && (board[i][2] == ' ')) {
        board[i][2] = tempcT;
    return 1;
    }
```

etc

Note there are also two wrong indexes, for instance using the second way for

```
for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
    if(board[i][1]==board[i][2] && board[i][0]!= ' '){
        board[i][0] = tempcT;
    return 1;
    }
}
```

you wanted (out of the missing test checking the cell is empty)

```
for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
    if(board[i][1]==board[i][2] && board[i][1]!= ' '){
        board[i][0] = tempcT;
    return 1;
    }
}
```

and for

```
for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
    if(board[1][i]==board[2][i] && board[0][i]!= ' '){
        board[0][i] = tempcT;
    return 1;
    }
}
```

you wanted (out of the missing test checking the cell is empty) :

```
for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
    if(board[1][i]==board[2][i] && board[1][i]!= ' '){
        board[0][i] = tempcT;
    return 1;
    }
}
```

Note in *checkWin* the loops are useless in :

```
//checks diagonals from top left to bottom right
for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
    if(board[0][0]==board[1][1] && board[1][1]==board[2][2] && board[0][0]!= ' '){
        return 1;
    }
}

//checks diagonals from bottom left to top right
for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
    if(board[2][0]==board[1][1] && board[1][1]==board[0][2] && board [2][0]!= ' '){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

it is enough to do

```
if(board[0][0]==board[1][1] && board[1][1]==board[2][2] && board[0][0]!= ' '){
    return 1;
}
if(board[2][0]==board[1][1] && board[1][1]==board[0][2] && board [2][0]!= ' '){
    return 1;
}
```